# Clicking through links in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have logged onto a third party website where I have a page full of URLs to click. I was able to collect the elements as such:

```
for i in num_alphabets:
    names = browser.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='client-name')
print(len(names)) # gives you the number of clients!!!
```

So now that I have this list called `names`, I want to know how I can click through all these elements. For now that would be enough, later on I want to have it store some information after clicking. I tried adding `.click()` at the end and it obviously won't work as `names` is a list.

Should I maybe create an array with only the first values of the list and then click through that? `browser.click()` isn't a valid attribute so I don't think that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ***names*** is the list of WebElements with value as *`client-name`*. So to click on each of those WebElements you have to iterate through the list. Incase the page doesn't changes and the *client-name* sections are on the same page you can use the following code block:

```
for name in names:
    name.click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was missing something very obvious, I couldn't figure out what. This is actually nearly everything that I have to do. The only thing left is a string comparison. Once I click the name, I want to get the element that has the string containing the number of appointments and if it is 1-4, store that name somewhere. Should I create a separate question for this? I tried getting the element and storing but it is giving me empty arrays

Comment: @diana18 Seperate ticket please.

Comment: I solved it actually my program is ready. Thank you though!!!